# Clarify an easily misunderstood editing reason in /help/editing

Tags: feature-request, comments, suggested-edits, help-center

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing

An example reason to edit is:

> To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

I recently ran into a subtlety with this editing reason. A user had added a comment to an answer, clarifying an explanation. I found this clarification useful, and from the votes, I presume other people did too.

So I submitted an edit suggestion, adding this information to the post.

This edit was rejected, and when I inquired why it was, I got the following explanation from a moderator for why the example given in the help page is not applicable in this case:

> Not third party comments. The only source of information in a post should be the post's author.

[Full context, in case I missed some important info](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382604/181955)
(But I'm specifically not interested in what the correct thing to do in this case is. I want the help centre text to be less easy to misunderstand)
**And to be very clear:** I have no objections to the edit being rejected because it was the right thing to do. There may even be multiple other reasons to reject it. But since an easy to understand (once you know it!) reason exists to not make the edit, this could all have been avoided.

---

This is an easy mistake to make! The correct interpretation of the editing reason requires one to deduce that "additional information only found in comments" means additional information *by the post author*, which is not a deduction I managed to figure out.

Could this example be reworded to make it less likely to interpret it in a way that implies relevant information could be added regardless of who wrote it?

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. I would have probably rejected that edit, as it's not clear to me that the author meant to say that. However, the moderator's reason (which is what you're actually asking about) seems a bit strong as an absolute statement. Adding third party comments can be ok in several cases IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Editing has both clear rules and general guidelines, sometimes those criteria aren't entirely clear-cut and perhaps they can't be.

For example, if you do 24 edits/day on Stack Overflow spread out evenly over a 24 hour period hardly anyone will notice the bumps on the main page. But on smaller sites like meta.SE users rely on the activity tab of the main page to keep track of recent events...Meaning if anyone edited/bumped 10 posts in 1 day that would cause a disturbance to the readers. Now compare that in volume with SO, if you were limited in number that way practically nothing could get edited...(The simple guideline is no bulk-editing in short periods, and even that may be necessary during burninations.)

In the specific case of [the edit you mention](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/382604/revisions)...The comment feels somewhat like an afterthought or an accessory to the objective straight-to-the-point short answer. It is a good comment but arguably can stay as a comment. Here it's hard to formulate a clear-cut rule because it depends subtly on how the question itself scopes the answers.

If the OP decided to give a short-answer I don't see the comment **adding vital technical information that isn't by itself evident or easy to deduce** (a strong criteria on SO for editing 3rd party comments into posts - and even that can't realistically be done when you have a dozen relevant technical comments).

(Think about it, if you had a hard rule to add comments to the post bodies shortly we'd see all kinds of tangential info getting edited into posts.)

So I venture to say in this case the mod made the right call, although synthesizing these vague guidelines into a clear set of hard rules might not be possible or even desirable. My advice to copy-editors who don't have the 2k privileges is to suggest edits they feel will be consensual with the reviewers and not to worry too much even if a good edit should be reject on occasion.

Comment: This seems to be answer to convince me that it was indeed the right call for the moderator to reject my edit. But there's actually little doubt about that, as a clear-cut policy exists that renders the edit unsuitable. My issue is the documentation of that policy, not the handling of the case.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys my intention in this post was not to justify the moderator (or to convince). I sought to highlight that there isn't a complete set of clear rules to editing. I could point you to dozens of meta threads with split opinions on what the right action in a given edit should be. Policy has been there are only a few hard rules, everything else are meta posts with more or less upvotes and editors/reviewers who follow those posts to varying degrees.

Comment: The issue is that this is not a policy meta post with some attempt at formulating good guidelines, it's a misleading example in the help centre documentation.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys yes but I've seen edits reject for each one of those "common reasons" in the help center. And sometimes people argue that all those reasons taken together are still not enough to justify an edit (I'm of the opposite opinion...) So if those reasons were to be removed, you'd end up with a "reasons to edit" section devoid of reasons...

Comment: I think the many alternate reasons to reject the edit is confusing the issue. My point is that even if it was, hypothetically, "adding vital technical information that isn't by itself evident or easy to deduce", it **still** would have been rejected for not being something written by the original author, while the help centre seemingly suggests the opposite.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys that's the part where your post gets really interesting, because I've never seen the 3rd party comment rule anywhere. That rule may be arqade.se specific and would need a complicated reasoning to sustain it. I've edited OP and 3rd party comments into posts several times when they were technically essential and the mods accepted the "no longer needed" flag on the comment. (Yes, in specific circumstances it can make the post and the thread better.)